# Rails caching issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For some reason when I visit my index action on my rails application I get weird results.  When its the first time i visit it, the results are as excpected, however, if I click on a link that takes me to another page and then press the back button, I get json results in my webpage verse HTML.

Here is my controller:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with(@users) do |format|
        format.json {
            render :json => @users.to_json(:methods => :available)
        }
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add format.html to the respond_with block. Add resp. views for the request formats under views and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105242/html5-history-api-json-displayed-when-going-back-to-another-page-and-then-f?answertab=votes#tab-top), maybe it can

> Chrome caches the pages you visit and when you go back or forward it
>   uses the cache to display the page quickly. If the URLs you are using
>   to retrieve JSON from the server by AJAX is the same one Chrome would
>   hit, then it's possible Chrome is picking that page from the cache,
>   which instead of being the nice HTML it's just a JSON dump.